# Excel: Looking up data and returning values from another spreadsheet

Tags: excel

In spreadsheet 2 I want to take the value in cell D [email address] and look up the email address on spreadsheet 1 in column D2:2000.  If there is a match by email address I want to return the corresponding cell value on spreadsheet 1 in column E to spreadsheet 2

I feel like VLookup may accomplish this but I can't seem to find an exact response.

MANY thanks for any help.

Anne

Answer (score 1):

If by Spreadsheet 2 and 1 you are referring to **two different workbooks**, then with both workbooks open, In Spreadsheet 2 enter the following formula (and you'll need to change Book1 and Sheet1 to whatever they really are) in Cell E2 (if D2 is where the 1st email address is) and fill down as many rows as you have:

`=VLOOKUP(D2,[Book1]Sheet1!$D$2:$E$2000,2,0)`

When you close and save the workbooks, it will establish a link between them that will prompt warnings when you open Spreadsheet 2. If you don't want that, you can copy the data from Spreadsheet 1 to Spreadsheet 2 and do what it says below.

However, if you just mean **different sheets within the same workbook**, then the following on the sheet where you want the data will do it (again, changing Sheet1 to whatever the name of the sheet is that has the original data):

`=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet1!$D$2:$E$2000,2,0)`

As a learning exercise, I'd recommend you play around with it to see how `VLOOKUP` works. For instance, rather than type in all of the text of the formulas directly, you can select what you want as you build the formula and the elements that refer to different workbooks and worksheets (like `Sheet1!`) will be automatically added for you. (I'd recommend this as a general strategy when coming to grips with ANY Excel function, in fact.)

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but it might be worth elaborating that the arcane syntax of off-sheet references does not need to be typed. In fact, it's very easy to get this part wrong, e.g., if there are spaces in the names. The easy way is to point to the off-sheet range as the formula is constructed. Excel will fill in the correct references.

Comment: @andyholaday Yes, you are right. That's kind of what I meant by "play around", but it isn't specific enough. I'll modify my answer.